# "collection was modified enumeration operation may not execute": error while deleting attachments from sharepoint list

Tags: development, sharepoint-server, visual-studio

I am trying to delete the attachments from my SharePoint 2013 list Programmatically :

```
foreach (string attachment in listitem.attachments)

{

  listitem.attachments.delete(attachment);
  listitem.update();

}
```

i am able to delete if there is only one attachment , but if i add multiple attachmemnts , on the second loop it gives me error : 
`"collection was modified enumeration operation may not execute"`.Any idea how i can delete multiple attachments.

Comment: Not related to exception you have but listitem.update(); is not needed when deleting attachments

Comment: @Revenant_01 could you please test if the snippet in my answer works fine? I've upvoted your answer, just want the code to host in SP.SO

Answer (score 1):

You are changing `listitem.attachments` inside `foreach` that was launched on that collection, that's why it's not going to work.

Try something like this:

```
int count = item.Attachments.Count
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    // action with item.Attachments[0] or item.Attachments.Delete(0)
}
```

---

**UPDATE**: My bad, `SPAttachmentCollection`'s indexer returns a filename as string, that is then to be passed to `Delete` or `DeleteNow` method. `DeleteNow` is faster and easier to read in code:

> If you delete an attachment by using the DeleteNow method, the
>   deletion takes effect immediately and you do not need to update the
>   list item to refresh version information

Snippet I posted first will work when dealing with `SPListItemCollection`. To delete from `SPAttachmentCollection`, this should work:

```
int count = item.Attachments.Count
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    item.Attachments.DeleteNow(item.Attachments[0])
}
```

Comment: For deleting objects you should really use a reverse for-statement

Comment: `for(int i = count - 1; i >= 0; i--)` and then `[i]`? Are you sure? I've always used usual `for` and `i`-less body without any troubles

Comment: I see now that you use `[0]` on each iteration, so that would work the same :)